# How to bring rows with search results on top in the datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, search, datagridview

Am trying to search for values through the datagridview using a column, i have  columns appliance type and appliances name , multiple appliances can have the same appliance, users will use the appliance type column to search

What i want is that when a user search for appliance type all the rows with the searched appliance type should come on top like some kind of sorting

Below is what i have tried but it only brings one row
Thanks in advance

```
private DataGridViewCell gettext(string searchtext,DataGridView dataGridView,int index)
        {
            dtgridappliance.MultiSelect = true;
            dtgridappliance.SelectionMode=DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
            DataGridViewCell met = null;
            foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
                {

                    if (row.Cells[index].Value != null && row.Cells[index].Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchtext.ToLower()))
                    {
                        met = row.Cells[index];
                        dtgridappliance.Rows[index].Selected = true;
                        this.dtgridappliance.Sort(dtgridappliance.Columns[0],ListSortDirection.Ascending);
                        dtgridappliance.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dtgridappliance.SelectedRows[i].Index;
                        break;
                    } 
                }
            }
            return met;
        }
```

Comment: When `gettext` method is called? - please [edit] your question and add a sample data with the current and expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is **How to bring rows with search results on top in the datagridview** and your current approach is attempting to use [DataGridView.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sort?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-windows-forms-datagridview-sort(system-collections-icomparer)) to work with the UI control directly.

If you're open to doing this another way, with `DataGridView` it's often easier to achieve your desired outcome by setting the `DataSource` property (in this case, a `BindingList<Appliance>`) and working with that list instead.

For starters, the DGV can be completely set up using ~10 lines in the `OnLoad` of the main form.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();
    private BindingList<Appliance> Appliances { get; }  = new BindingList<Appliance>();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        // Set up the DGV and add a few appliances.
        dtgridappliance.DataSource = Appliances;
        Appliances.Add(new Appliance(ApplianceType.Refrigerator, "Maytag" ));
        Appliances.Add(new Appliance(ApplianceType.Refrigerator, "LG" ));
        Appliances.Add(new Appliance(ApplianceType.Microwave, "Amana" ));
        Appliances.Add(new Appliance(ApplianceType.Dishwasher, "Samsung" ));
        Appliances.Add(new Appliance(ApplianceType.Dishwasher, "Whirlpool" ));
        dtgridappliance.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        // Format columns
        dtgridappliance.Columns[nameof(Appliance.Name)].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

        // Populate the combo box and add a handler for when the combo box changes
        object[] values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ApplianceType)).Cast<object>().ToArray();
        comboBoxSearch.Items.AddRange(values);
        comboBoxSearch.SelectedIndex = (int)ApplianceType.Refrigerator;
        comboBoxSearch.SelectionChangeCommitted += onSearchByApplianceType;
    }
}
```

Where the class representing a Row of data looks something like this:

```
enum ApplianceType { Dishwasher, Microwave, Refrigerator  }
class Appliance
{
    public Appliance(ApplianceType applianceType, string name)
    {
        ApplianceType = applianceType;
        Name = name;
    }
    public ApplianceType ApplianceType { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

[image: datagridview with sort]

---

The sort requires a way to compare a given `Appliance` to the type selected in the combo box:

```
private int compareToSelectedType(Appliance appliance)
{
    return appliance.ApplianceType.Equals(comboBoxSearch.SelectedItem) ?
        0 : 1; // Ones that match will sort before ones that don''t.
}
```

---

Now, when the combo box changes, you can remove all the DataGridView items and put them back in a different order.

```
private void onSearchByApplianceType(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Use System.Linq to sort a new temporary list.
    var tmp = new List<Appliance>(
        Appliances
        .OrderBy(_=>compareToSelectedType(_))
        .ThenBy(_=>_.Name));

    // Remove all items from the DataGridView
    Appliances.Clear();

    // Put them back in with the new order.
    foreach (var appliance in tmp)
    {
        Appliances.Add(appliance);
    }
}
```

This is "just one way" to do it, but I [tested](https://github.com/IVSoftware/datagrid-view-sort.git) it and it works. Hope this helps get you closer to your intended outcome.